# Where do IDEA download gradle to on macOS?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

IDEA downloaded a gradle for one of my project and I have no idea where it stores to (not locally or globally), I like to reuse this file because my download speed is like 5kbps...

Where would I find the downloaded gradle file(e)?

Comment: What do you mean by "downloading a gradle"?  Do you mean dependencies or actually means gradle itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ uses the standard Gradle wrapper to download Gradle distributions. The downloaded distributions are stored in ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists